# How to Retrieve file content from content Document in chunks using SOQL

Tags: apex

We have users uploading files(content Document) to opportunities. They are able to upload files where the size is greater than 100MB. But salesforce has a heap size limit of 12MB for asynchronous apex. I need to upload these files to AWS s3. I am running into exceeding heap size governor limit when retrieving the file content(contentversion->version Data) which is expected. 
1. How can I query chunks of file content using SOQL, so I can upload chunks of 5MB to s3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in Apex. The most reasonable way to handle this would be to download the file from an external source, such as a web browser, Heroku or AWS EB app, etc, then process the upload from there.

Comment: Do we have the ability by any chance now ? or the answer is still valid

Comment: @brahmajitammana Not in Apex. I think today one could reasonably use a Aura/Lightning Web Component and load the file in to the browser's memory and upload, but still not in Apex.

Comment: @sfdcfox, Can Salesforce Evergreen functions (Release with Spring 21) be the answer for this problem?

Comment: @MayurBirari Yes, functions can conceivably handle this scenario by uploading 3-5MB chunks and then stitching them together in repeated calls to a Function. I'd still rather just use the File Blob Upload API, which can handle up to 2GB in a single pass, but for smaller files that are still way too large for Apex, this could conceivably work.